# I used Python Selenium to choose a "Year" from the dropdown box, clicked "search," and it apparently worked. But the data says otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu

There is a [page](https://www.cpbl.com.tw/standings/history) with tables of statistics I'm trying to pull.

The page has the default year as 2020, with a dropdown box to select different years. I wrote this code to select 2009.

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import numpy as np
import re
import pandas as pd

driver=wd.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.cpbl.com.tw/standings/history')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Year'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('2009')

button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='查詢']")[0]
button.click()

main=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[(@id = "PageListContainer")]')[0]
main_att=main.get_attribute('innerHTML')
tab=pd.read_html(main_att)
```

I purposely didn't say driver.close() to leave the browser open, so I can look at it, and apparently the selection of 2009 worked. The browser had tables for 2009. However, the data my code pulled was still from the default year (2020). I want data from 2009. Anyone know why?

I am using Python 3.7 and Spyder 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

To select ***2009*** from the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) and extract the *innerHTML* of the *PageListContainer* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.cpbl.com.tw/standings/history")
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#Year")))).select_by_visible_text("2009")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='查詢']"))).click()
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'PageListContainer']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Console Output:

```
    <!--上半季戰績-->
    <div class="RecordTableWrap">
        <div class="record_table_caption">上半季戰績</div>

        <div class="record_table_swipe_guide" style="display: none;">
            <div class="desktop"></div>
            <div class="mobile"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="record_table_scroll_ctrl" style="display: none;">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="scroll_left"></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="scroll_right"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="RecordTableOuter">
            <div class="RecordTable">
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <th class="sticky">
                            <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                <div class="rank">排名</div>
                                <div class="team-w-trophy">球隊</div>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="num">出賽數</th>
                        <th class="num">勝-和-敗</th>
                        <th class="num">勝率</th>
                        <th class="num">勝差</th>
                            <th class="num">中信兄弟</th>
                            <th class="num">樂天桃猿</th>
                            <th class="num">統一7-ELEVEn獅</th>
                            <th class="num">富邦悍將</th>
                        <th class="num">主場戰績</th>
                        <th class="num">客場戰績</th>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">1</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=ACN011">中信兄弟</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">37-0-23</td>
                            <td class="num">0.617</td>
                            <td class="num">-</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">8-0-12</td>
                                                <td class="num">16-0-4</td>
                                                <td class="num">13-0-7</td>

                            <td class="num">18-0-12</td>
                            <td class="num">19-0-11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">2</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=AJL011">樂天桃猿</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">34-0-26</td>
                            <td class="num">0.567</td>
                            <td class="num">3</td>
                                                <td class="num">12-0-8</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">9-0-11</td>
                                                <td class="num">13-0-7</td>

                            <td class="num">18-0-12</td>
                            <td class="num">16-0-14</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">3</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=ADD011">統一7-ELEVEn獅</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">26-0-34</td>
                            <td class="num">0.433</td>
                            <td class="num">11</td>
                                                <td class="num">4-0-16</td>
                                                <td class="num">11-0-9</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">11-0-9</td>

                            <td class="num">13-0-17</td>
                            <td class="num">13-0-17</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">4</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=AEO011">富邦悍將</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">23-0-37</td>
                            <td class="num">0.383</td>
                            <td class="num">14</td>
                                                <td class="num">7-0-13</td>
                                                <td class="num">7-0-13</td>
                                                <td class="num">9-0-11</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>

                            <td class="num">13-0-17</td>
                            <td class="num">10-0-20</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--上半季戰績 end-->
    <!--下半季戰績-->
    <div class="RecordTableWrap">
        <div class="record_table_caption">下半季戰績</div>

        <div class="record_table_swipe_guide" style="display: none;">
            <div class="desktop"></div>
            <div class="mobile"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="record_table_scroll_ctrl" style="display: none;">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="scroll_left"></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="scroll_right"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="RecordTableOuter">
            <div class="RecordTable">
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <th class="sticky">
                            <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                <div class="rank">排名</div>
                                <div class="team-w-trophy">球隊</div>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="num">出賽數</th>
                        <th class="num">勝-和-敗</th>
                        <th class="num">勝率</th>
                        <th class="num">勝差</th>
                            <th class="num">中信兄弟</th>
                            <th class="num">樂天桃猿</th>
                            <th class="num">統一7-ELEVEn獅</th>
                            <th class="num">富邦悍將</th>
                        <th class="num">主場戰績</th>
                        <th class="num">客場戰績</th>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">1</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=ADD011">統一7-ELEVEn獅</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">32-1-27</td>
                            <td class="num">0.542</td>
                            <td class="num">-</td>
                                                <td class="num">13-1-6</td>
                                                <td class="num">10-0-10</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">9-0-11</td>

                            <td class="num">16-0-14</td>
                            <td class="num">16-1-13</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">2</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=AEO011">富邦悍將</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">31-1-28</td>
                            <td class="num">0.525</td>
                            <td class="num">1</td>
                                                <td class="num">9-1-10</td>
                                                <td class="num">11-0-9</td>
                                                <td class="num">11-0-9</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>

                            <td class="num">15-1-14</td>
                            <td class="num">16-0-14</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">3</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=ACN011">中信兄弟</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">30-2-28</td>
                            <td class="num">0.517</td>
                            <td class="num">1.5</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">14-0-6</td>
                                                <td class="num">6-1-13</td>
                                                <td class="num">10-1-9</td>

                            <td class="num">16-1-13</td>
                            <td class="num">14-1-15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">4</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=AJL011">樂天桃猿</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">60</td>
                            <td class="num">25-0-35</td>
                            <td class="num">0.417</td>
                            <td class="num">7.5</td>
                                                <td class="num">6-0-14</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">10-0-10</td>
                                                <td class="num">9-0-11</td>

                            <td class="num">16-0-14</td>
                            <td class="num">9-0-21</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--下半季戰績 end-->
    <!--全年戰績-->
    <div class="RecordTableWrap">
        <div class="record_table_caption">全年戰績</div>

        <div class="record_table_swipe_guide" style="display: none;">
            <div class="desktop"></div>
            <div class="mobile"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="record_table_scroll_ctrl" style="display: none;">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="scroll_left"></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="scroll_right"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="RecordTableOuter">
            <div class="RecordTable">
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <th class="sticky">
                            <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                <div class="rank">排名</div>
                                <div class="team-w-trophy">球隊</div>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="num">出賽數</th>
                        <th class="num">勝-和-敗</th>
                        <th class="num">勝率</th>
                        <th class="num">勝差</th>
                            <th class="num">中信兄弟</th>
                            <th class="num">樂天桃猿</th>
                            <th class="num">統一7-ELEVEn獅</th>
                            <th class="num">富邦悍將</th>
                        <th class="num">主場戰績</th>
                        <th class="num">客場戰績</th>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">1</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=ACN011">中信兄弟</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">120</td>
                            <td class="num">67-2-51</td>
                            <td class="num">0.568</td>
                            <td class="num">-</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">22-0-18</td>
                                                <td class="num">22-1-17</td>
                                                <td class="num">23-1-16</td>

                            <td class="num">34-1-25</td>
                            <td class="num">33-1-26</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">2</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=AJL011">樂天桃猿</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">120</td>
                            <td class="num">59-0-61</td>
                            <td class="num">0.492</td>
                            <td class="num">9</td>
                                                <td class="num">18-0-22</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">19-0-21</td>
                                                <td class="num">22-0-18</td>

                            <td class="num">34-0-26</td>
                            <td class="num">25-0-35</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">3</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=ADD011">統一7-ELEVEn獅</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">120</td>
                            <td class="num">58-1-61</td>
                            <td class="num">0.487</td>
                            <td class="num">9.5</td>
                                                <td class="num">17-1-22</td>
                                                <td class="num">21-0-19</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="num">20-0-20</td>

                            <td class="num">29-0-31</td>
                            <td class="num">29-1-30</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sticky">
                                <div class="sticky_wrap">
                                    <div class="rank">4</div>
                                    <div class="team-w-trophy">

                                        <a href="/team?TeamNo=AEO011">富邦悍將</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="num">120</td>
                            <td class="num">54-1-65</td>
                            <td class="num">0.454</td>
                            <td class="num">13.5</td>
                                                <td class="num">16-1-23</td>
                                                <td class="num">18-0-22</td>
                                                <td class="num">20-0-20</td>
                                        <td class="num">&nbsp;</td>

                            <td class="num">28-1-31</td>
                            <td class="num">26-0-34</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--全年戰績 end-->
```

Comment: That page is still the default page (2020) unfortunately. :(

For 2009, the first hyphenated number should be 34-2-24.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I used `time.sleep(10)`